# Weird clipping when finishing anime.js animation

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I'm working on a chain of animations and when it all ends, it seems there's some weird ghosting going on. For a split of a second, my elements are shown in the original state, with a lower opacity.

```js
anime({
  targets: '#big-lock',
  strokeDashoffset: [0, 5],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 350,
  delay: 250,
  easing: 'easeInSine'
});

anime({
  targets: '#lock-line',
  strokeDashoffset: [0, 3],
  translateY: [{
      value: '-2px',
      duration: 550,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
    {
      value: '2px',
      duration: 550,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
    {
      value: '-2px',
      duration: 550,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
  ],
});

anime({
  targets: '#inner-circle',
  translateY: [{
      value: '-1px',
      duration: 250,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
    {
      value: '1px',
      duration: 250,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
    {
      value: '-1px',
      duration: 250,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
    {
      value: 0,
      duration: 250,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    },
  ],
}).finished.then(() => {
  anime({
    targets: '.plugins-not-installed-text',
    translateY: [{
      value: '10px',
      duration: 750
    }]
  });
  anime({
    targets: '#lock-wrapper',
    translateY: [{
      value: '-10px',
      duration: 750
    }]
  });
  anime({
    targets: '#plugins-not-installed-screen',
    opacity: 0
  }).finished.then(() => {
    $('#plugins-not-installed-screen').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#plugins-not-installed-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#plugins-not-installed-screen .upper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 24px 48px;
  background-image: url('../Images/component.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.demo-install-content .demo-components {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.plugins-not-installed-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#lock {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 65px;
}

#plugins-not-installed-screen #lock {}

#plugins-not-installed-screen #big-lock {
  stroke-dasharray: 61 62;
  stroke-dashoffset: 5;
  /* go to 5 */
}

#plugins-not-installed-screen #lock-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 31 33;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  /* go to 3 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.1.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<div id="plugins-not-installed-screen" class="">
  <div class="upper">
    <div id="lock-wrapper">
      <svg version="1.1" id="lock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 35" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 35;" xml:space="preserve">
                                <style type="text/css">
                                    #big-lock{fill:none;stroke:#686868;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                                    #inner-circle{fill:none;stroke:#686868;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                                    #lock-line{fill:none;stroke:#686868;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                                </style>
                                <path id="big-lock" d="M4.4,13.5c-1.2,0.8-2,2.1-2,3.6v4c0,2.8,1.1,5.4,3.1,7.4c1.9,1.9,4.5,2.9,7.2,2.9
                                    c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c5.5-0.1,10-4.9,10-10.5v-3.8c0.1-1.8-0.9-3.3-2.4-4l-6.5-2.7c-0.8-0.3-1.8-0.4-2.6,0L10.1,11"/>
                                <circle id="inner-circle" cx="12.7" cy="21.9" r="2.9"/>
                                <path id="lock-line" d="M7.1,15.1V9.9c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.6-5.6h0c3.1,0,5.6,2.5,5.6,5.6v8"/>
                            </svg>
    </div>
    <h5 class="plugins-not-installed-text">Plugins not installed.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to work around the CSS, see if there's something I'm missing or if CSS makes the animation itself reset due to default values but...nothing.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the default animation `ease` is set to some weird curve. When you have this combined with opacity, a kind of "jump values" happens, so, it'll go back to some lower opacity for a second due to the easing.

Just set `easing` to `linear`.